# Index query formula

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to index the query formula so that it outputs on the row where it matches much like Vlookup?

I need something other then Vlookup because it only matches on the first column, and can not use match index because it only returns the match and I need to return multiple columns

Thanks

```
=query(CouncilsLink!B:Q, "select B,D,F where D matches'"&TEXTJOIN("|",false,Elements!B1:B123)&"'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an If statement with Regexmatch:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(regexmatch(CouncilsLink!D:D,TEXTJOIN("|",true,Elements!B1:B123)),{CouncilsLink!B:B,CouncilsLink!D:D,CouncilsLink!F:F},""))
```

Where CouncilsLink contains

[image]

Elements contains

[image]

and the result is

[image]

Or you could use Vlookup or Match like this

```
=ArrayFormula(if(iserror(vlookup(CouncilsLink!D:D,Elements!B:B,1,false)),"",{CouncilsLink!B:B,CouncilsLink!D:D,CouncilsLink!F:F}))

=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(match(CouncilsLink!D:D,Elements!B:B,0)),{CouncilsLink!B:B,CouncilsLink!D:D,CouncilsLink!F:F},""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this where Col1 and Col2 are columns you want to fetch and A3 is a column you want to match with

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHeet ID","SheetName!StartColumn:EndCoumn"), "select Col1,Col2 where Col1="&$A3,0),"")
```